# Repeat "If" query consequently in jQuery

Tags: jquery, velo

I would like to repeat an "If" query permanently to retrieve a piece of information and perform an action accordingly.

This should be used to display content only when a user is logged in.
Currently the query happens once as soon as the page is loaded. The problem is that when a user logs in after the page is loaded, the content does not appear and the page has to be reloaded. This is my current code:

```
import wixUsers from 'wix-users';
   
$w.onReady( () => {
if (wixUsers.currentUser.loggedIn) {
$w('#html1').show();
$w('#button17').show();
$w('#box9').hide();
$w('#button29').show();

}
else {
$w('#html1').hide();
$w('#button17').show();
$w('#box9').show();
$w('#button29').hide();

}
});
```

How is it possible to always check this?
Probably the solution for this is relatively simple, but I don't know much about jQuery. I appreciate any support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want code to run after successful log-in then try `wixUsers.onLogin` (this needs to run inside `onReady` function).

```
import wixUsers from 'wix-users';
    
wixUsers.onLogin((user) => {
  let userId = user.id;
  let isLoggedIn = user.loggedIn;
  let userRole = user.role;
} );
```

You should be able to integrate the code snippet into your code by adding the following:

```
import wixUsers from 'wix-users';

function toggleLoginState(isLoggedIn) {
    if (isLoggedIn) {
        $w('#html1').show();
        $w('#button17').show();
        $w('#box9').hide();
        $w('#button29').show();

    }
    else {
        $w('#html1').hide();
        $w('#button17').show();
        $w('#box9').show();
        $w('#button29').hide();

    }
}

$w.onReady(() => {
    toggleLoginState(wixUsers.currentUser.loggedIn); // Set default state once page has finished loadading.

    wixUsers.onLogin((user) => {
        toggleLoginState(user.loggedIn); // This should always be true.
    });
});
```

More details can be found in the documentation https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/wix-users/onlogin

Comment: Thanks for ur answer! Unfortunately this doesn't work. Maybe I'm just doing it wrong? Could u may send me this piece of code embedded into mine so I just need to copy and paste it?

Greetings

Comment: I've update the answer so you can integrate it into your code.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It now finally work how we want it to  If you want to see the page you helped us to build just view it here: [https://www.dronec.de/flycommun](https://www.dronec.de/flycommun)